# Assetic multiple images in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have following lines in config.yml:

```
assetic:
    # ...
    assets:
        image1:
            input: @bundle/Resource/images/image1.png
            output: images/image1.png

        image2:
            input: @bundle/Resource/images/image2.png
            output: images/image2.png
```

**How to copy a few files at once or by mask?**

For example:

```
assetic:
    # ...
    assets:
        images:
            input: @bundle/Resource/images
            output: images
```

or:

```
assetic:
    # ...
    assets:
        images:
            input: @bundle/Resource/images/*.png
            output: images/*.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you add images in your `config.yml` ?

Prefer the `assets:install` command. It copy your `Bundle/Resources/public` directory to your `web` directory. So put your images in `Bundle/Resources/public/images`, run the command and use yours assets in you view :

```
{% image '@Bundle/Resources/public/images/image.png'%}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="">
{% endimage %}
```